# remap right alt to behave as right ctrl

Tags: xmodmap

I'm trying to remap my <kbd>right alt</kbd> to behave like my <kbd>right ctrl</kbd> so I can use my right thumb to press the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> button. This is Ubuntu 12.04.

I've created the file .Xmodmap in my home folder with the following content:

```
clear control
clear mod1
!keycode 64 = Alt_L Meta_L
keycode 108 = Alt_R Meta_R
add control = Control_L Control_R Alt_R
add mod1 = Alt_L Meta_L
```

As you might guess, my left alt key has keycode 64 and my <kbd>left alt</kbd> key has keycode 108.

This actually works in the sense that my right alt key behaves as if I press the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key.

However my left <kbd>alt</kbd> key now doesn't do anything anymore, which means I don't have an <kbd>alt</kbd> key left. This is strange given that `xmodmap` gives the following output:

```
xmodmap:  up to 4 keys per modifier, (keycodes in parentheses):

shift       Shift_L (0x32),  Shift_R (0x3e)
lock        Caps_Lock (0x42)
control     Control_L (0x25),  Control_R (0x69),  Alt_R (0x6c)
mod1        Alt_L (0x40),  Alt_L (0xcc),  Meta_L (0xcd)
mod2        Num_Lock (0x4d)
mod3      
mod4        Super_L (0x85),  Super_R (0x86),  Super_L (0xce),  Hyper_L (0xcf)
mod5        ISO_Level3_Shift (0x5c),  Mode_switch (0xcb)
```

The strange thing is that when I remove the Alt_R mapping onto <kbd>control</kbd>, the <kbd>alt</kbd> keys work.

(ie., change the second to last line to:)

```
add control = Control_L Control_R
```

Now even my right alt behaves as an <kbd>alt</kbd> key which confuses me. After removing the Alt_R mapping from the control line the output of `xmodmap` gives:

```
xmodmap:  up to 4 keys per modifier, (keycodes in parentheses):

shift       Shift_L (0x32),  Shift_R (0x3e)
lock        Caps_Lock (0x42)
control     Control_L (0x25),  Control_R (0x69)
mod1        Alt_L (0x40),  Alt_L (0xcc),  Meta_L (0xcd)
mod2        Num_Lock (0x4d)
mod3      
mod4        Super_L (0x85),  Super_R (0x86),  Super_L (0xce),  Hyper_L (0xcf)
mod5        ISO_Level3_Shift (0x5c),  Mode_switch (0xcb)
```

Hope you guys can help.

ps. I used [this](http://earthviaradio.wordpress.com/2012/02/06/swapping-the-left-alt-and-ctrl-keys-in-ubuntu-11-10/) website as a source.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to simply use *Keyboard Layout >> Options >> Ctrl key position >> Right Alt as Right Ctrl*, but this doesn't work. This has already been filed against Debian as [Bug#663218](http://lists.debian.org/debian-x/2012/03/msg00109.html)

1. Start fresh by deleting `~/.Xmodmap`.
2. Note that you do not need to *clear* Control and Mod1. This makes it easier to change only what you want. Your `~/.Xmodmap` shoud be:

   ```
   !Swap right control and right alt
   remove Control = Control_R
   remove Mod1 = Alt_R
   keycode 105 = Alt_R
   keycode 108 = Control_R
   add Control = Control_R
   add Mod1 = Alt_R
   ```

Answer (score 2):

If you are one of the unfortunate people like me that could not get xmodmap to switch right Alt with right Ctrl, then maybe this will help.

**If you press right Alt and e and you get é then this solution is for you (needs improvement).**

Run this in the terminal (check your keycodes with xev):

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 108 = Alt_R Meta_R Alt_R Meta_R"
```

then put this code in your .Xmodmap:

```
remove Control = Control_R
remove Mod1 = Alt_R
keycode 105 = Alt_R
keycode 108 = Control_R
add Control = Control_R
add Mod1 = Alt_R
```

This code sets your Alt_Gr key to Alt_R, and then it swaps Alt_r with Ctrl_R.

If you want this to remain after you logout, put the following commands in any of your startup shell files, for example ~/.profile:

```
if [ -f $HOME/.Xmodmap ]; then
  xmodmap -e "keycode 108 = Alt_R Meta_R Alt_R Meta_R"
  /usr/bin/xmodmap $HOME/.Xmodmap
fi
```

sources: [question1](https://superuser.com/a/383243/586011) [question2](https://askubuntu.com/a/280058/390931)

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu 19.04, To make the mapping system-wide, you should change two files:

- /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/altwin
- /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc

Add the following section to the former one:

```
// Ctrl is mapped to the Alt.
partial modifier_keys
xkb_symbols "right_alt" {
    key <LALT> { [ Alt_L, Meta_L ] };
    key <RALT> { type[Group1] = "TWO_LEVEL",
                 symbols[Group1] = [ Control_R, Control_R ] };
    modifier_map Mod1 { Alt_L, Alt_R, Meta_L, Meta_R };
    modifier_map Control { <LCTL>, <RALT> };
};
```

And substitute `include "altwin(meta_alt)"` to the `include "altwin(right_alt)"` in the latter.

Comment: This answers the question and works.  But the accepted answer swaps the right alt and right ctrl.  This is not was was originally asked, but I think it's a solution many are looking for (having two controls on the right isn't so handy).  Would you mind adding how to map right control to right alt?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a much simpler way.

Add that command to autostart or .xinitrc:
`setxkbmap -option ctrl:ralt_rctrl`

It forces right alt to behave like right control. I also recommend to check out [other setxkbmap options](https://gist.github.com/jatcwang/ae3b7019f219b8cdc6798329108c9aee), there are some useful ones.

Comment: Any chance you can expand on how you have this set up? I'm having trouble getting it working

Comment: I think this doesn't work because `ctrl:ralt_rctrl` isn't on the list. `ctrl:rctrl_ralt` exists.