# Set Context Menu key to function as Right Control

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, xmodmap

Dell notebooks in Brazil and possibly other countries no longer ship with a right control key.

This is bad for ergonomics, so I would like to set the context menu key to function as right control.

How may this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enter `System Settings` > `Keyboard Layout` (in `Personal` group). Open `Layouts` tab (if you have multiple layouts), press `Options...` button. There you can find `Ctrl key position` group. Check `Menu as Right Control button`, then apply new settings.
*Update: in the newer systems you may need to install GNOME Tweaks to adjust advanced configuration settings ([link](https://askubuntu.com/a/1248023)).*

**For KDE:** run `System Settings`, open `Input devices` in `Hardware` group and in `Keyboard` section open `Advanced` tab. There you can find the same `Ctrl key position` group with `Menu as Right Control button` checkbox.

Comment: nice, found that on kde too

Comment: Would you please describe the KDE way to make this answer complete?

Comment: No longer works in ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Answer (score 2):

Write to `~/.Xmodmap`:

```
! dell removed the right control: change context menu to right control
!keycode 135 = Menu NoSymbol Menu
remove Control = Control_R
keycode 105 = Control_R NoSymbol Control_R
keycode 135 = Control_R NoSymbol Control_R
add Control = Control_R
```

And to `~/.xinitrc`:

```
if [ -f $HOME/.Xmodmap ]; then
  /usr/bin/xmodmap $HOME/.Xmodmap
fi
```

Based on [remap right alt to behave as right ctrl](https://askubuntu.com/questions/237564/remap-right-alt-to-behave-as-right-ctrl) and https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xmodmap.