# Need to Rebind Left Arrow Key to Right Control Key

Tags: keyboard

I spilled the tiniest amount of water on my laptop and now the left arrow key won't respond - can anyone give me a quick runthrough of how to reassign it (i'm using Ubuntu) to another key (probably the right <kbd>ctrl</kbd> or another)?

If the tutorial requires me to press the left arrow key (perhaps to get its binding ID or something) I won't be able to do that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[setkeycodes](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/man8/setkeycodes.8.html) can then be used to re-assign scancode to keycode mappings.

(only know of, because usually the caps-lock are the first ones I disable)

```
sudo setkeycodes E01D 105
```

where E01D is the scancode for right-ctrl and 105 is the keycode for cursor-left.

There's even a visual editor for the mapping, I just found:

[set context menu key to function as right control](https://askubuntu.com/questions/321510/set-context-menu-key-to-function-as-right-control?rq=1)

Comment: how exactly do I work out which key is the left arrow key? I just a bunch of random numbers when I run getkeycodes

Comment: try dumpkeys - is a rather human-readable format... here it's mapped to keycode 105 = Left

Comment: just be aware that on a notebook keyboard this might vary.

Comment: OK so keycode 105 is for the left arrow - what is the setkeycodes command to set this to the right control?

Comment: updated answer - without ANY guarantee, please validate.

Comment: What's your scan code for the left control (the usual ctrl)?

Comment: Ok I got it working - thanks so much! You answer is by far the simpliest. Just to clarify I used sudo setkeycodes 1d 97 to set the left control back to the left control. SO 1) find the scan code (call it A) - this can be found on a list online just type what is the can code of ... - and use dumpkeys to find the keycode (call it B). Then just use sudo setkeycodes A B

Comment: Here's the simple way to reassign keys...

1) Find the scan code of the the key you want to assign something to (for example this is 1d for the left control - see http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/kbd/scancodes-1.html for a list of what these are. You can also use sudo showkeys -s

2) Use sudo dumpkeys to find the 'keycode' for the key you want to move (left arrow is 105 on my machine for example - may vary depending on machine)

3) dial in sudo setkeycodes 1d 105  --->  this makes your machine perform 'left arrow' whenever you press the left cntrl key.

Comment: validating is always better - because I've sometimes seen exotic notebook keyboards which had certain keys mapped strangely (ones from far east in combination with euro keyboards).

Comment: `showkey --scancodes` & `xev` are also useful for finding the codes.... while `evtest` seems to be useful, in particular for USB keyboard events.