# How do I change keyboard keys configuration on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: gnome, keyboard, 20.04, keys

I had Ubuntu MATE 18.04, and I could change keys like "*Ctrl is mapped to Win and usual Ctrl keys*", or "*Alt is mapped to Right Win*...", those options for me were very useful, that let me adapt keyboards of different laptops to have similar functionality.

This was an example in Ubuntu 18.04, MATE desktop:
[image]

Now I have **Ubuntu 20.04 with GNOME** desktop, but I can't find any system-options to configure these "keyboard keys distribution".

Is there any way to change it in GNOME desktop?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An advanced option like this is not available in the pre-installed *Settings* application, you need to use *(GNOME) Tweaks*. First install it by running the following command in Terminal (you would have to [enable the universe repo](https://askubuntu.com/q/148638/480481) first if it's disabled):

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```

Then launch it and you would find the option under **Keyboard & Mouse** > **Additional Layout Options**:

[image: gnome-tweaks in Ubuntu 20.04]

Comment: Is there any way to just change keys around for a specific keyboard, as opposed to every keyboard?