# How to change keyboard model in Ubuntu 23.04 (GNOME) running Wayland?

Tags: gnome, keyboard, keyboard-layout, chromebook

I am running Ubuntu on a Chromebook, and the media keys don't work because Ubuntu treats the keyboard as a regular, generic keyboard with 105 keys.

In MATE Desktop, [there is a way](https://askubuntu.com/a/1451098/124466) to change the keyboard layout (i.e. keyboard model), and so is there in KDE.

[image]
(MATE keyboard layout settings)
[image]
(KDE's keyboard layout settings)

How can I do this in GNOME?

GNOME settings offer me the option to change the layout to that of another language, but not the keyboard model.

Comment: I found [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1248023/124466), but the options in GNOME tweaks are limited. It allows me to (say) map the ctrl key to another key, but not the full keyboard layout (Chromebooks have a very specific keyboard layout).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the keyboard model you can run this command:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

Changes you make via that command will be written to the `/etc/default/keyboard` file. Note, though, that GNOME Settings also may write to that file, and if that happens, the keyboard model setting will be overwritten (since GNOME does not know about it), and you will need to run the above command again.

Comment: I tried this and was able to select "Chromebook" and it didn't do anything, even after rebooting. I see that `/etc/default/keyboard` even shows chromebook as well, but Ubuntu doesn't respect it. I'm also on 23.10 and am unable to change the layout in the input settings.