# Make Control_R behave like menu Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Tags: keyboard, settings

I'd like right control button on my laptop keyboard to bring up context menu. In previous versions it was possible inside 'Settings' app. What now?

Comment: How exactly did you do it before?  What is the setting you used to use?  Have you exhausted keyboard shortcuts?  Please give us more information.  How can we help if you know more about the issue than you've shared with us?

Comment: Perhaps you will find your option or something else that works well in Gnome Tweaks, Keyboard tab, Additional layout options.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/321510/set-context-menu-key-to-function-as-right-control