# Set Right Control key to function as the Context Menu key

Tags: shortcut-keys, kde5, context-menu

unfortunately my laptop does not have a menu key; can I reassign the right ctrl key to the menu key?

I basically want the exact opposite of this: [Set Context Menu key to function as Right Control](https://askubuntu.com/questions/321510/set-context-menu-key-to-function-as-right-control)

Is that somehow possible?

FYI: I use a Kubuntu derivative

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Neon
Description:    KDE neon User - 5.24
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```

Comment: Hello. Please be clear on what version you are using. Is it Kubuntu and if so what version.

Comment: added output of 'lsb_release -a' to be clear about the linux distribution

Comment: Only Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use a KDE/Neon forum.    *FYI:   KDE Neon does share a number of support options common with Kubuntu, alas this is not one of them with Neon off-topic here*

Comment: Methods that work in Kubuntu 20.04 LTS will use Qt 5.12.8 LTS (ie. the LTS library/toolkit) may not match your non-20.04 system.  Only parts of the KDE Neon stack are the same as Kubuntu, with the KDE change also requiring Qt5, KF5 & other parts of the stack to use non-LTS versions...

Comment: @guiverc can I move the question to over there or do I have to copy and paste it?

If theres a non GUI way of reassigning the key I'd be happy to do so (without KDE dependend stuff)

Comment: When closed; the question can be migrated to SE *Unix & Linux* where you'll be on-topic...  Kubuntu & KDE Neon however don't share support options on a Stack Exchange or Ubuntu site (*such as this one*)