# How do I remap right ctrl to right alt?

Tags: shortcut-keys, xmodmap

I've got right alt remapped to ctrl (via [remap right alt to behave as right ctrl](https://askubuntu.com/questions/237564/remap-right-alt-to-behave-as-right-ctrl)), now I need my ctrl to be an alt. thanks for help with this

Comment: does `setxkbmap -option 'ctrl:rctrl_ralt'` do what you want?  (it won't survive logout/login but as a test ...)

Comment: How did you map right alt to ctrl?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/237564/remap-right-alt-to-behave-as-right-ctrl

Comment: `xmodmap` is a deprecated tool.  if it works for you, great, but i wouldn't recommend mixing an `xmodmap` solution with an XKB solution.

Answer (score 3):

I would add `setxkbmap -option 'ctrl:rctrl_ralt'` to the startup applications

1. Open up the startup applications menu by searching `startup applications` in the dash.
2. Click `Add` and set the command to `setxkbmap -option 'ctrl:rctrl_ralt'`.
3. (optional) Set the name and/or comment.

EDIT: Thanks @quixotic for the command

Comment: don't do that.  that's a good testing command to make sure the change works; under GNOME or KDE its changes will be reset very quickly.

Comment: What do you mean by reset?

Comment: @quixotic - could you please then add a answer on how to change it permanently?

Comment: It would follow this format, which works well https://askubuntu.com/questions/237564/remap-right-alt-to-behave-as-right-ctrl But I'm too inexperienced to figure out the specific remap I'm looking for

Comment: @wilf no. on further information from the OP this question is seeking an `xmodmap` solution.  i can't help with that.

Comment: @quixotic it doesn't have to mix as long as it replaces it

Answer (score 3):

You may achieve the result by editing the `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc` file.
Find the line starting with `key <ALT>` and replace Alt_R to Control_R.
If you want to swap right control with right alt, you need also find the line starting with `key <RCTL>` and do analogically. Then relogin to the system.
Works on Ubuntu 18.10 gnome-shell 3.30

Comment: my gnome-shell 3.22.3 works well, too.